# Write Grunt task to console

Tags: javascript, bash, gruntjs, uglifyjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

This is relevant to any Grunt task which has a source file and a destination (output file).

When I run `grunt` in my command line, I don't want Grunt to write anything to file, I just want to view (return) the output to my console, be it Bash, CMD or any CLI.

Lets take uglify for example.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({
    uglify: {
          options: {
            mangle: true,
            sourceMap: true,
          },
          build: {
            src: 'js/foo.js',
            dest: 'js/foo.min.js' <-- Don't need this.
          }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify']);
};
```

Instead of `Done, without errors`, when successful, I want to view the uglifed code in the console.

For context, I need this for a command line application which won't need anything written to disk. I just need to use the output on the fly (I'm trying to avoid writing to file and re-reading from the CLI).

Comment: `/dev/stdout` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You could write directly to `/dev/stdout` ( not on windows tough ):

```
build: {
    src: 'js/foo.js',
    dest: '/dev/stdout'
}
```